# How to use particle effects like mentioned?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, coordinate-systems

I am developing a multi-platform game on android studio using **libGDX** library and **java** language.

The game requires the player to maneuver a main ship across 2D space using mouse input.

I am using the given `ParticleEffect` class in libGDX library to show its exhaust but there is a slight problem that looks like this...

This is the [standing ship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCJkG.jpg)
and
This is when its [moving upward](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EQyh.jpg)

**I need every particle to move only downwards respective to the ship regardless the ship is standing or moving.**
This means that I need to add the change in (x,y) coordinates of ship into each particle of exhaust but the problem is that the (x,y) coordinates of that class are **private** and there is no function that lets me make any direct changes to the coordinates of individual particles.

How do I make that happen?

Comment: Please provide your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, if I understood the question right. But probably, you can solve your issue via marking the emitter as attached. In this case if you change draw coordinates of ParticleEffect from (x0,y0) to (x1,y1), then every particle, which is already emitted, will be moved by (x1-x0, y1-y0) as well.

See the screenshot:
[image: Attachment option in libgdx ParticleEditor]

Comment: Thanks a lot, That solved half of my problem,
The other half being How to make it look natural...Well that is up to me.